# Dedicated System Monitoring Display Software?

Tags: software-recommendation, temperature, cpu-load, monitoring, output

I have a display hooked up to my server which I plan to have an always-on system monitoring readout. Things like system temps, load percentages, console output, the like.

Looked for a bit and I can't seem to find what I am looking for. Any help?

Comment: Cockpit is quite good for that.

Answer (score 1):

I am using "conky" which is highly configurable and can look good (using the right themes) An example can be seen [here](https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-conky-themes-for-linux/)

For getting your sensor data and more information (like Network, ram ,cpu usage an more) conky provides you with a editable config file.

[Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/beginners-guide-to-conky-4043352) has recently put out an article about how to install and to configure. Many more pages are available...